# Facing error with my connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I know that this question has been repeated a lot, but sincerely I have tried to fix it and find where the error is, but I couldn't find it and solve it, so that's why I post my question here. The problem with this code its giving me error message:

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

at the end of the code. Can someone please help me with it?

```
 protected void editHPPersInfobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection EdPersInfoCon = new SqlConnection(sc);
        SqlCommand EditUsrInfoCMD = new SqlCommand();

        var UsrNme = Session["UsrNme"];

        string FileExtentiona = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(EditImgFUP.FileName);
        string FileExtentiona2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(EditPersInfologoFileUp.FileName);
        string FileExtentiona3 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(EditPesInfoBizImg1FU.FileName);
        string FileExtentiona4 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(EditPesInfoBizImg2FU.FileName);
        string FileExtentiona5 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(EditPesInfoBizImg3FU.FileName);



        if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
            {
       if (EditImgFUP.HasFile || EditPersInfologoFileUp.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg1FU.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg2FU.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg3FU.HasFile)
         {
             var files = new[] { FileExtentiona, FileExtentiona2, FileExtentiona3, FileExtentiona4, FileExtentiona5 };
             files = files.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
             var extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };

           if ((files.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
         {

                if (EditImgFUP.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/") ||
                EditPersInfologoFileUp.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/") ||
                EditPesInfoBizImg1FU.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/") ||
                EditPesInfoBizImg2FU.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/") ||
                EditPesInfoBizImg3FU.PostedFile.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/"))
                    {

                        string EditUsrInfoSQL = @"Update UserInfo SET  FN=@FN, LN=@LN, Password=@Password, RePass=@RePass, Website=@Website, Post=@Post, Email=@Email, Address=@Address, TeleNum=@TeleNum, Facebook=@Facebook, GooglePlus=@GooglePlus, Twitter=@Twitter, Img=@Img, Logo=@Logo, image1=@image1, image2=@image2, image3=@image3 Where UID=@UID";


                        EditUsrInfoCMD.Connection = EdPersInfoCon;
                        EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandText = EditUsrInfoSQL;

                        EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme);
                        EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FNEDTTXTBX.Text);
              //...


                        string imgnouser = "/images/general/nouser.jpg";
                        string[] imagesUI = GetImagess(Convert.ToString(UsrNme));


                        if (EditImgFUP.HasFile)
                        {
                            EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", EditImgFUP.FileName);
                            EditImgFUP.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + EditImgFUP.FileName));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagesUI[0]))
                            {
                                EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", imgnouser);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", imagesUI[0]);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

        else
        {
            EditPersInfoImgFrmtWarnLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
            EditPersInfoImgFrmtWarnLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            EditUsrPan.Visible = true;
        }

        }


                else
                {

                    string EditUsrInfoSQL = @"Update UserInfo SET  FN=@FN, LN=@LN, Password=@Password, RePass=@RePass, Website=@Website, Post=@Post, Email=@Email, Address=@Address, TeleNum=@TeleNum, Facebook=@Facebook, GooglePlus=@GooglePlus, Twitter=@Twitter Where UID=@UID";

                    EditUsrInfoCMD.Connection = EdPersInfoCon;
                    EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandText = EditUsrInfoSQL;

                    EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme);
                    EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FNEDTTXTBX.Text);
                    EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", LNEDTTXTBX.Text);
                    EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PASSEDTTXTBX.Text);
                 //...

                }


                EdPersInfoCon.Open();
                int result = EditUsrInfoCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    // Updated successfully;
                }
                EditUsrPan.Visible = false;
                ReHPPersInfo();
                showusrinfo.Visible = true;

            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two branches in your `if...elses` where you don't assign the connection to the command:

```
if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
{
    if (EditImgFUP.HasFile || EditPersInfologoFileUp.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg1FU.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg2FU.HasFile || EditPesInfoBizImg3FU.HasFile)
    {
        if ((files.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
        {
            if (....)
            {
                EditUsrInfoCMD.Connection = EdPersInfoCon;
                EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandText = EditUsrInfoSQL;

                EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme);
                EditUsrInfoCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FNEDTTXTBX.Text);
            }
            // !!! HERE  !!!
        }
        else
        {
             // !!! HERE  !!!
            EditPersInfoImgFrmtWarnLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
            EditPersInfoImgFrmtWarnLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            EditUsrPan.Visible = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        string EditUsrInfoSQL = @"Update UserInfo SET  FN=@FN, LN=@LN, Password=@Password, RePass=@RePass, Website=@Website, Post=@Post, Email=@Email, Address=@Address, TeleNum=@TeleNum, Facebook=@Facebook, GooglePlus=@GooglePlus, Twitter=@Twitter Where UID=@UID";
        EditUsrInfoCMD.Connection = EdPersInfoCon;
        EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        EditUsrInfoCMD.CommandText = EditUsrInfoSQL;
    }
```

Why don't you assign it where you initialize the `SqlCommand`?

```
SqlConnection EdPersInfoCon = new SqlConnection(sc);
SqlCommand EditUsrInfoCMD = new SqlCommand();
EditUsrInfoCMD.Connection = EdPersInfoCon;
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your reply, The first one after if i dont think its need cuz i already assign it in the beginning and the second part inside else statement also i dont think i need to assigned as in my other page i have something similar code  and i did not do as you mention and its work. But please could update your answer and replacing // HERE !! with what you think i have to do so i will try it and i hope it will work

Comment: @Alfred: you just need to assign the connection where you initialize the command as i've shown above. That's the safest approach. What i can say is that you currently have two conditions where the command's connection is not assigned. The first `HERE` is a missing `else` of the inner `if`, the second `HERE` applies when `files.Except(extensions).Count()) > 0` and when `EditPersInfoImgFrmtWarnLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";`